# Can't build Cordova Windows 8 project with node.js and npm

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, cordova

I try to install node-v0.10.26-x64.msi and cordova(PhoneGap) 3.4.0 for Windows 8. But it occurs an error on Windows 8.1(x64).

This is a result on Windows 8.1 command prompt(as an Administrator) for building:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g cordova
C:\Windows\system32>cd c:\data
c:\Data>cordova create abc com.aaa.bbb ccc
c:\Data>cd abc
c:\Data\abc>cordova platform add windows8
Project created
[Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: ]
c:\Data\abc>cordova build
[Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: ]
Running command: cmd args=["/c","c:\\Data\\abc\\platforms\\windows8\\cordova\\bu
ild"]
cordova library for "windows8" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "windows8"
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "windows8"
Preparing windows8 project
Procesabcg configuration changes for plugins.
creating jsproj from project at : C:\Data\abc\platforms\windows8\CordovaApp.jspr
oj
Iterating over installed plugins: []
Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
[Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: �]
Running command: cmd args=["/c","C:\\Data\\abc\\platforms\\windows8\\cordova\\bu
ild"]
c:\Data\abc\platforms\windows8\cordova\lib\build.js(57, 5) WshShell.Exec: file not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-whitespace issue was solved by adding "contents = contents.substring(contents.indexOf("<"));" to "contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')" into "node_modules\cordova..\xml-helpers.js".

But "build.js(57, 5) WshShell.Exec" error is not resolve.

Comment: if(contents.indexOf("<")!=0) console.error('WARNING: ' + filename + ' is not starting with <'); ... helped me to identify the problem